# Paginate large data in Laravel

Tags: laravel, pagination

Good day, I just want to ask on how to handle a large amount of data to be display in my table. For instance, I have a table in my app and it will be fetching millions of data and paginate it by 100. What is the best approach in doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to paginate it, instead of fetching whole table to memory (that will be heavy).

In raw SQL it is done by `LIMIT X OFFSET Y`

In Laravel eloquent's pagination() is doing this for You, for ex. `User::paginate(100);`

Then You simply foreach this data in Your table, and put pagination links under it.

Read more https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer. I will read the detailed explanation of laravel pagination on their documentation.